# Modifying DOM of a html page from background javascript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How do I modify DOM  html page from background script? The html page exists in the extension's root folder. When then page is opened the URL is looked like "chrome-extension://hffffemnacblbojccelnkhnafndfkhgc/block.html"

**File tree in my extension:**

```
css/
  bootstrap-theme.css
  bootstrap-theme.css.map
  bootstrap-theme.min.css
  bootstrap.css
  bootstrap.css.map
  bootstrap.min.css
  popup.css

fonts/

img/    
  128-128.png
  1413232635_virus detected 2.png
  16-16.png
  48-48.png

js/ 
  block.js
  bootstrap.js
  bootstrap.min.js
  event.js
  jquery-1.11.1.js
  jquery.cookie.js

block.html

manifest.json

popup.html
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Viper Security ATD",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Viper Security Advance Threat Defence.",
   "icons": {
    "48": "img/48-48.png",
    "128": "img/128-128.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/16-16.png",
       "default_title": "Viper Security Advance Threat Defence",   
          "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },


  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/jquery-1.11.1.js","js/event.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "permissions": [
  "<all_urls>",
  "tabs",
  "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Make your question clearer, what do you want to do? Inject a page from your extension folder to where?

Comment: I want Modify dom of a HTML page of my extension from background javascript. The page exists on my extension's root.
 the page url looking like:chrome-extension://hffffemnacblbojccelnkhnafndfkhgc/block.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want Modify dom of a HTML page of my extension from background javascript. The page exists on my extension's root. the page url looking like:chrome-extension://hffffemnacblbojccelnkhnafndfkhgc/block.html

Technically, you can do that.

If the page with `block.html` is open, the background page can get a reference to its `window` object with [this code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews):

```
var win = chrome.extension.getViews("tab").filter(
  function(w) {return w.location.pathname == "/block.html"}
)[0];

win.document.getElementById("foo").value("bar"); // Modify that page
win.somefunc(); // Call a global function in that page
// etc.
```

It is probably cleaner, however, to use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and send messages from the background script that will be received by every `block.html` open.

Note: you can't modify the actual files, you can only modify the DOM of an opened document.

Comment: I tried your code taht is working but I got a problem.
In console what the error giving is: "Uncaught Error: Invocation of form extension.getViews(string, function) doesn't match definition extension.getViews(optional object fetchProperties)"

Comment: Aaah, it's a very old function that's synchronous. I did not test the code, sorry. I'll fix it in a minute.