# Matching content script with last keyword match

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a page in block.html in extension directory. I want match content script with the page name.

Check my manifest file below, there is content_script match:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Cobra Security ATD",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Cobra Security Advance Threat Defence.",
   "icons": {
    "48": "img/48-48.png",
    "128": "img/128-128.png"
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/16-16.png",
       "default_title": "Cobra Security Advance Threat Defence",   
          "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },


  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/jquery-1.11.1.js","js/event.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*block.html"],
            "js": ["js/jquery-1.11.1.js","js/block.js"]
        }
    ],

  "permissions": [
  "<all_urls>",
  "tabs",
  "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What's the relation to the packaged block.html? Explain the logic you're going after.

Comment: If "block.html" match the script  will work in the block.html page

Comment: Actually the the extension's block.html when will be loaded the script can change dom of the block.html page. The URL of that page is appearing as "chrome-extension://hffffemnacblbojccelnkhnafndfkhgc/block.html". Ptoblem with ""content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*block.html"],
            "js": ["js/jquery-1.11.1.js","js/block.js"]
        }
    ],"    . How will i match it in manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does *not* inject content scripts into `chrome-extension://` pages. You cannot indicate this schema in the manifest, and you can't indicate a host permission that would allow you to inject it.

Since it's an extension that you control, you **don't need** to inject scripts for anything!

- If you want to put code in it, you.. put code in it, in a `<script
  src="...">` fashion.
- If you want to inform the page of some event, you use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).
- If you want to pass some information when you open the page, you can
  use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229882/chrome-extension-open-the-captured-screen-shot-in-new-tab/26233795#26233795), sending a request back for data.

Comment: Thank you @Xan for your useful answser, Can you give me please a sample that can pass message from background script to the /block.html page

Comment: @Touhid Before I answer, is that the right direction to initiate the message? Do you want to send a message because something has happened in the background page, or you want to communicate when the page opens?

Comment: I want suggestion from you how will I pass some value from background  script? The block.html page is opened  by a background event. Same  event  pass some value to the block.html page. How is this possible?  In this question -> [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409377/modifying-dom-of-a-html-page-from-background-javascript[/link] you wanted to give me the latest working code, if u give me I will be helped so much.

Comment: When something happens on background page I want open the block.html page and want pass value or message from bg script

Comment: This would be a good schema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229882/chrome-extension-open-the-captured-screen-shot-in-new-tab/26233795#26233795 Essentially, open the page, and then send a message back from it requesting data.